# Unable to start IBM HTTP Server on Linux

Tags: linux, webserver, http

I am trying to install IBM HTTP Server 7.0 on my Linux machine 2.6.32-504.el6.x86_64. When i finish installation and try to start IHS using command `/opt/IBM/HTTPServer/bin/apachectl start`, i get below error :

```
/opt/IBM/HTTPServer/bin/apachectl: line 80: @@SERVERROOT@@/bin/httpd: No such file or directory
```

Can anyone suggest what could be the cause and how can i resolve it?

Comment: Possible [solution](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21676380)?

Comment: I have no such directory as postinstall and no such xml logs. Also, hostname is properly defined in /etc/hosts already.

Comment: Is @@SERVERROOT@@ defined in the apache config file? It appears to point to a wrong (non existing) directory...

Comment: Now i am getting this error : `./apachectl: line 100: /opt/IBM/HTTPServer/bin/httpd: cannot execute binary file`

Comment: Do i need to have WAS plugin to run it ? however i dont have websphere in the architecture.

Comment: Issue is resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Missing libraries was the reason of this kind of error. Here's the link which helped me troubleshoot this error.

https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.installconfig.doc/admin/t_troubleshooting_ihs_startup.html